# Função sort() torna atributo data="" undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou utilizando a função `sort()` para ordenar algumas divs. Mas estou com alguns problemas.

Utilizo o atributo `data=""` para adicionar um `JSON`. Mas por ele ter muitos bytes e ser usado em milhares de divs, prefiro usar o mesmo dinamicamente com Jquery. Pois quando inspeciono o elemento no navegador, se torna rápido.

O problema ocorre quando uso a função `sort()` por duas vezes listando as divs. Na segunda vez ela acaba deletando o atributo data, retornando `undefined`.

Agora, se eu adicionar diretamente no código o atributo, não ocorre este tipo de problema.

Como faço para adicionar dinamicamente e não ter este problema?

Deixo um exemplo parecido com o meu código, basta clicar duas vezes no botão `erro_2_clicks`, e depois clicar na div `lista` que gera o erro:

ex: https://jsfiddle.net/pjga86x7/3/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //AQUI GERA O ERRO
  $(".lista").each(function(a, b) {
    $(b).data("id", a + 1);
  });

  $(document).on("click", ".erro_2_clicks", function() {
    var div = $(".lista");
    div.sort(function(a, b) {
      return $(b).data("id") - $(a).data("id");
    });
    $(".errado").html(div);
  })

  $(document).on("click", ".lista", function() {
    console.log($(this).data("id") + " Erro com 2 clicks")
  })

  //ESCREVER DIRETAMENTE NO CÓDIGO FUNCIONA NORMALMENTE
  $(document).on("click", ".certo_2_clicks", function() {
    var div = $(".lista_certo");
    div.sort(function(a, b) {
      return $(b).data("certo") - $(a).data("certo");
    });
    $(".certo").html(div);
  });

  $(document).on("click", ".lista_certo", function() {
    console.log($(this).data("certo") + " certo")
  })


})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="lista">1</div>
<div class="lista">2</div>
<div class="lista">3</div>
<div class="lista">4</div>
<div class="lista">5</div>
<div class="lista">6</div>
<div class="lista">7</div>
<div class="lista">8</div>
<div class="lista">9</div>
<div class="lista">10</div>
<div class="errado"></div>
<button class="erro_2_clicks">Erro 2 click</button>

<div data-certo="1" class="lista_certo">1</div>
<div data-certo="2" class="lista_certo">2</div>
<div data-certo="3" class="lista_certo">3</div>
<div data-certo="4" class="lista_certo">4</div>
<div data-certo="5" class="lista_certo">5</div>
<div data-certo="6" class="lista_certo">6</div>
<div data-certo="7" class="lista_certo">7</div>
<div data-certo="8" class="lista_certo">8</div>
<div data-certo="9" class="lista_certo">9</div>
<div data-certo="10" class="lista_certo">10</div>
<div class="certo"></div>
<button class="certo_2_clicks">Certo 2 clicks</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `.data()` é uma propriedade jQuery atribuída ao elemento. Ao fazer o `.sort()`  e depois inserindo o resultado com `.html()` pela segunda vez, essa propriedade fica vazia.

Em vez de usar `.html()`, use `.appendTo()` que todas as propriedades dos elementos serão conservadas.

Troque:

```
$(".errado").html(div);
```

Por:

```
div.appendTo(".errado");
```

Comment: Perfeito, deu certo. Eu havia usado o attr(), mas travou a página, nem consegui carregar. Seria interessante você deixar a instrução do attr, algo que nem tinha ideia.